# use rand() number to echo array values

Tags: php, arrays, random

I am using rand() function to generate a random number.
I want to echo array values based on this random number.

My code is as follows:

```
$total = rand(0,20);
```

In case the output is '3', i want to have three values echoed, i.e:

```
$listItems[0] . $listItems[1] . $listItems[2]
```

In case the output is '5', i want to have five values echoed, i.e:

```
$listItems[0] . $listItems[1] . $listItems[2] . $listItems[3] . $listItems[4]
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this please?

Comment: [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) on the required length. Then [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to a string

Comment: Most basic approach: `for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) ...`…

Comment: You could use a good old fashioned for loop too `for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++){$listItems[$i])}`

Answer (score 0):

or you could use a for loop

```
$total = rand(0,20);
for ($i=0;$i<=$total;$i++)
{
    echo $listItems[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [@0stone0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625547/0stone0)'s comment. You can avoid a loop here and just use [`array_slice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [`implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

*Note my example uses PHP 8's named parameters when using the `array_slice()` method*

```php
$total = rand(0, count($items)); // Get a random number between 0 and the number of items in the array
$reducedItems = array_slice($items, length: $total); // Reduce the items array to only contain the int stored in $total
echo implode($reducedItems); // Echo all the items left, will not exceed $total
```